# Comparing current image in collection to previous image in collection using Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, change-detection

I am wanting to subtract one binary raster from another, for all images in a collection. For example if I have ten images, I want to subtract image 2 from image 1, image 3 from image 2, image 4 from image 3... image 10 from image 9, to create a new binary raster for each one of these subtractions, displaying change between the two images.

I have included my code below, which applies the masks and creates the binary rasters in the first half, and then attempts this raster subtraction in the last half. I get the error "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'name' in undefined", which I understand but cannot figure out another way.

```
/* Computes collection IDs and then clips images, applies cloud and water masks, NDSI and then displays all images */
var computedIds = clip.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['system:index'])
                          .get('list');
computedIds.evaluate(function(ids) {
  for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
    //Mask each layer and display
    var image = ee.Image("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/"+ids[i]);
    var clipped = image.clip(ee.FeatureCollection("users/rgi60_all"));
    var snow = masked(clipped)
    // Add all layers to map
    Map.addLayer(snow, {bands:'NDSI'}, ids[i], false);
    // Create for loop which subtracts image binary raster from previous image binary raster !!!!!!!!!!!! NOT WORKING !!!!!!!!!!!!!
    for (var i1=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
     if (i1===0){ // do nothing
      }
      else { // selects the 'snow' binary band from each image and subtracts to give new raster named 'change'
        var change = ids[i1-1].select('snow').subtract(ids[i1].select('snow')).selfMask()}}}
      Map.addLayer(change, {}, ids[i], false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not a common one. You are using a lot of client side code that is not recommended (see [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server)). Besides, you did not provided enough information, so I made some assumptions and made up a site for my testing.

The images in the resulting collection will have values of -1 if the change is positive (new snow) and 1 if negative (lost snow), according to your approach:

```
var change = ids[i1-1].select('snow').subtract(ids[i1].select('snow'))
```

I painted blue the new snow and red the snow gone.

Code here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/4dd5841ecb4be094ac0d04b256fadd9b

```
var site = ee.Geometry.Point([-71.6494781770138, -42.97085867205123])

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
                   .filterBounds(site)
                   .filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(180, 270)) // Snow time
                   //.limit(10)  // limit for testing purposes

var ndsi = function(img) {
  var index = img.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6'])
  var mask = index.gt(0).rename('snow')
  return mask
}

var masked = collection.map(ndsi)
var masked_list = masked.toList(masked.size())

var ini = masked_list.slice(0,1) // list with first image
var rest = masked_list.slice(1) // rest of the list

var change_list = ee.List(
  rest.iterate(function(img, ini) {
    ini = ee.List(ini)  // cast variable
    var last_image = ee.Image(ini.get(-1)) // get last image
    var actual_image = ee.Image(img)
    var diff = last_image.subtract(actual_image)

    // keep changes only
    var change = diff.neq(0)

    return ini.add(diff.updateMask(change))
}, ini))

var change = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(change_list.slice(1))

var last = ee.Image(change.sort('system:time_start', false).first())

Map.addLayer(last, {palette:['blue', 'red']}, 'last image of the collection')
```