# Get difference between images in image collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am wanting to figure out how to get the difference between images at t and t-1 in an image collection in Google Earth Engine, but just can quite figure out how to use .iterate to do it. For accumulating values, the .iterate() function works great, but I am not sure how to pass in image_t and image_t-1 into the difference function.

Here is some code that will calculate accumulated NDVI for a year. How would I get the difference between images and save to a collection? It seems similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296882/comparing-current-image-in-collection-to-previous-image-in-collection-using-goog), but I just can't quite figure out how to make it work.

```
    // Define the area of interest
    var ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-77.1637, 34.8526,-76.9501, 34.9798);
    
    function maskS2clouds(image) {
      var qa = image.select('QA60')
    
      // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
      var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
      var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
    
      // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
      var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
                 qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
    
      // Return the masked and scaled data, without the QA bands.
      return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
          .select("B.*")
          .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
    }

function ndvi_Sentinel2(image){
    // Use the normalizedDifference(A, B) to compute (A - B) / (A + B)
    var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename("NDVI");
    return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

var calc_difference = function(image,list){
  var previous = ee.Image(ee.List(list).get(-1));
  // Add the current anomaly to make a new cumulative anomaly image.
  var image_unmasked = ee.Image(image).unmask(0);
  var current = image_unmasked.add(previous)
    // Propagate metadata to the new image.
    .set('system:time_start', image_unmasked.get('system:time_start'));
  // Return the list with the cumulative anomaly inserted.
  return ee.List(list).add(current);
};

// Load a Sentinel collection for the area of interest.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterBounds(ROI)
    .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
    .map(maskS2clouds)
    .map(ndvi_Sentinel2);
    
print(collection);

var ndvi_list = collection.select("NDVI").toList(999);

var first = ee.List([collection.first().select("NDVI")]);

var accumlatedNDVI = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(ndvi_list.iterate(calc_difference, first)));

print(accumlatedNDVI);

// Display the results.
Map.centerObject(ROI);
var ndviParams = {bands: ['NDVI'], min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
var rgbVis = accumlatedNDVI.map(function(img) {
  return img.visualize(ndviParams);
});

// Define GIF visualization parameters.
var gifParams = {
  'region': ROI,
  'dimensions': 600,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
  'framesPerSecond': 10
};

// Print the GIF URL to the console.
print(rgbVis.getVideoThumbURL(gifParams));
```

Comment: This question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300473/calculate-difference-of-subsequent-images-in-a-collection) basically answers how to do it. If anyone cares, I'll write up a more detailed answer.